# WPF - Take screenshot - System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, bitmap, screenshot

I am trying to get a screenshot of the displays connected to a pc, and return the result as a byte[] 
The Display class is WindowsDisplayAPI.

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the screenshot to be displayed
/// </summary>
/// <param name="display"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static byte[] GetImage(Display display)
{
    // Define bitmap
    using (Bitmap sc = new Bitmap(display.GetScreen().Bounds.Width, display.GetScreen().Bounds.Height, 
                      System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
    {
        if (sc == null)
            return null;

        // Define graphics object
        using (Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(sc))
        {
            if (memoryGraphics == null)
                return null;

            memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(display.GetScreen().Bounds.X, display.GetScreen().Bounds.Y, 0, 
                  0, display.GetScreen().Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
            BitmapSource tmp = CreateBitmapSourceFromGdiBitmap(sc);
            JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
            byte[] bit = new byte[0];                    
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                 encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(tmp));
                 encoder.Save(stream);
                 bit = stream.ToArray();
                 stream.Dispose();
                 stream.Close();
             }

             GC.Collect();
             return bit;                                       
         }
    }
}
```

together with a helper method

```
/// <summary>
/// Helper for GetImage 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="bitmap"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private static BitmapSource CreateBitmapSourceFromGdiBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
{
     #region
      // Transform the image for CaptureScreen method
      if (bitmap == null)
           throw new ArgumentNullException("bitmap");

      var rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);

      var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(
                rect,
                ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

       try
       {
            var size = (rect.Width * rect.Height) * 4;

            return BitmapSource.Create(
                bitmap.Width,
                bitmap.Height,
                bitmap.HorizontalResolution,
                bitmap.VerticalResolution,
                System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Bgra32,
                null,
                bitmapData.Scan0,
                size,
                bitmapData.Stride);
        }
        finally
        {
            bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
        }
            #endregion
        }
```

I don't believe I got a memory leak, although not certain. The method works fine if I take normal static screen, but throw System.OutOfMemoryException: 'Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.' if I try to get screenshot of videos, for example.

Here is further details: 
2021-02-11 16:32:52,395 ERROR SSDS.Main.Core.WindowsMethods - System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid. 
at System.Drawing.Graphics.GetHdc()
at System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX, Int32 sourceY, Int32 destinationX, Int32 destinationY, Size blockRegionSize, CopyPixelOperation copyPixelOperation)
at SSDS.Main.Core.WindowsMethods.GetImage(Display display) in WindowsMethods.cs:line 204 
at SSDS.Main.Core.WindowsMethods.d__26.MoveNext() in WindowsMethods.cs:line 364
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Drawing.dll

 This is line 204: 
memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(display.GetScreen().Bounds.X, display.GetScreen().Bounds.Y, 0, 0, display.GetScreen().Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

 
If I send the application as x64, It works fine however I see the memory usage climb to just under 2GB, while it stays below 900MB with any cpu set. So I am guessing the image created in unnecessary large, how could I reduce to let's say 300 pixels width? 
Or is the problem somewhere else?

Comment: Are you building this as a 32-bit, x86 application? Also, I'm a little confused as to which problem you are trying to solve. You mention two different exceptions; `OutOfMemoryException` and `ArgumentException`. Which one are you trying to address?

Comment: The exzception I am addressing is part of the subject, the second is thrown because of it. All works fine if I use 64-bit, this is more trying to get the proper fix for all environments, and not just a quick fix..

Comment: So is the `memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen` line the one throwing the `OutOfMemoryException`?

Comment: Yes, this is correct

Comment: What is the type for `Display`? I was experimenting with your code and I'm thinking the problem may be a Win32 API call issue.

Comment: The type for display is WindowsDisplayAPI from nuget, then you can do a simple iteration such as: foreach (Display display in Display.GetDisplays())

Answer (score 0):

change GetImage() method to this. Probably because of the `Desktop` also gives a message.

```
public static byte[] GetImage()
{
   // Define bitmap
   double screenLeft = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenLeft;
   double screenTop = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenTop;
   double screenWidth = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth;
   double screenHeight = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight;

   using (Bitmap sc = new Bitmap((int)screenWidth, (int)screenHeight, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
   {
       if (sc == null)
          return null;

       // Define graphics object
       using (Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(sc))
       {
          if (memoryGraphics == null)
             return null;

          memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen((int)screenLeft, (int)screenTop, 0,
               0, sc.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
          BitmapSource tmp = CreateBitmapSourceFromGdiBitmap(sc);
          JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
          byte[] bit = new byte[0];
          using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
          {
             encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(tmp));
             encoder.Save(stream);
             bit = stream.ToArray();
             stream.Dispose();
             stream.Close();
          }

          GC.Collect();
          return bit;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however this is a multi screen application and I need to pass the correct display as parameter. Furthermore, the returned image size is incorrect.

Comment: You have to give the part you want with exact coordinates. It does not work because of the coordinates.

Comment: Sorry, but that makes no sense to me.